# Jquery change color of list items randomly

Tags: jquery, random, html-lists

So im new to jquery and I want to make a new navigation menu. I want this jquery script to color my list items randomly in a variety of colors of my choosing. Lets just say red, yellow, green, blue and black. Also it should not be possible to have the same color before and after a color is selected.

Further more I want this menu to have a hover function, so that once you hover one of the list items, all the other list items get the color of grey or another css value.

I hope someone could help me build this.

I know I haven't done much yet.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="nav">
        <ul id="navigation">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Products</li>
            <li>Blog</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#navigation, li').addClass('blue');
});
```

**CSS**:

```
* {
    margin:0px; padding:0px;
}
body {
    background-color:#999;
}

#wrapper {
    width:960px; margin:auto; background-color:#CCC;
}
.blue {
    color:#567;
}
```

Demo on jsfiddle, link: http://jsfiddle.net/iBertel/vbpXP/11/

Comment: Why are you wanting to apply the different colours using jquery?

Comment: Well i want to apply different class using jquery and then color it with css... What would be smarter??

Comment: Yeah I know that, but why? Why not just give each of the elements a class to begin with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using @massivePenguin's idea 
Here you go, basically, we create an array, a few css rules with a default hover state of grey on all elements in the list. We end up with this result which has a randomised colour effect.

This is the key that randomises your array. The magic happens here, to make this a better effect, add 5 or so more colours to the array to add to the "random" effect.

```
colours.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()});
```

The above code is the key factor in the below script.

```
var colours = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green', 'pink'];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#navigation li').hover(function() {
        colours.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()});
        $(this).addClass(colours[0]);
    }, function() {           
        $(this).removeClass(colours[0]);      
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/QkWXN/

Comment: Yes almost, i just need the colors on the list items active so that 1 is red, another is yellow, third is blue etc. and then only when you hover an list item all other list items should lose their color and get a new color (like grey)

Comment: I have edited my answer for you.

Comment: @user1562679 This does all you have asked for, randomises the colours so that each time you hover over the same link it's different, all others become grey once hovered. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks a lot. Just one last thing... all the list items needs to be colored when not hovered and when hovered only the hovered should have color and the rest should grey out... Is this fixable?

Comment: Glad to have helped, +1 to @massivePenguin because he gave me the idea. Sometimes the simplest of things can make the best difference.

Comment: Just one last thing... all the list items needs to be colored when not hovered and when hovered only the hovered should have color and the rest should grey out... Is this fixable?

Comment: I have edited my fiddle for you. @user1562679

Comment: Thats just perfect! Thanks again - love how simple its made. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

1. Put your classes into an array (e.g. var colours = ['red','yellow','green','blue','black'])
2. Shuffle the array (see [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-a-javascript-array))
3. Instantiate a counter variable (e.g. n)
4. Use an .each() function to:

   - Apply the value of the colour array's counter index (eg colours[n]) to the list item on hover
   - Increment the counter variable (e.g. n++)

e.g.

```
$('#nav li').each(function(){
    var switchColour = colours[n];
    $(this).hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass(switchColour);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass(switchColour);
    })
    n++;
});
```

Comment: This sounds interesting, can you jsfiddle a solution please?

Comment: JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DsxHz/

Comment: Ah i see your fiddle... nice! Is it possible to make the script add a random class of 5 different classes instead of that n1? So that i can use css to color em? 

I meen so i dont have to add a class my self from the beginning.

Comment: n is a counter variable - it's a numeric value that starts at 0 and is incremented by 1 for each list item in $(#nav), so its final value in this example would be 4. To use more colours, just add them to the array; providing you have at least as many colours in the array as you do list items, you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: yes i understand, but this way i will need to add a class to my li for it to work right? EDIT: Actually this can work! Thank you very much, saved my day.

Comment: n is used to pick the nth element in the colours array: e.g. if colours is ['red','blue','green','yellow','black'] then colours[3] would be 'yellow' (arrays in Javascript are zero-indexed, meaning the first element is [0] and not [1]; that's why we start n off at 0).

Comment: There's no need to use JavaScript for the hover event. Just use `:hover` on the CSS classes.

Comment: true! You'd then only need to use .addClass for each li rather than the whole hover() function.

Comment: I have noticed that yours doesn't actually randomise the colours that are changing, I have posted a change to your code that fixes this with much less script too.

Comment: This is exactly how my answer is working...

Comment: I don't mean to argue @MarcusEkwall, although if you view your fiddle, the colours are not randomising. You can also do this with a lot less code. Just trying to help.

Comment: You also don't need to use a counter in my version. It's very simple

Comment: Shannon can you post a fiddle of a working solution? I also still need to make it so that when i hover one of the list items all other items will turn grey - is this possible?

Comment: @Shannon Colors have been randomized all the time. Not sure you are looking at my answer, and I'm not arguing ;) just pointing out that my answer fixes everything he is asking for, with the minimum amount of code.

Comment: @MarcusEkwall It doesn't randomise on hover, which is exactly what he was asking for. Although he didn't point this out in his original question. What he originally asked for can be achieved with css lol :)

Answer (score 0):

So you can achieve this with the following code:

```
$('#navigation li').mouseover(function () {
    // this in this context is the currently hovered list DOM element.
    $(this).siblings().addClass('desired-class');
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('desired-class');
});
```

Just a note:

You have the same ID on two different elements. You should change that.

Comment: Yea i see, that was a mistake - its corrected :-) 

Your code doesnt tell me how i can get each list item to get different colors (does it? It needs to pick one a certain number of classes and apply it) and not the same color as the list item before?

Comment: You'd be better off using [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) for this kind of behavior.

Comment: But i dont see how this is applying a random color to my list items?

Answer (score 0):

For random colors on load, but not on hover, use this:

```
$(function(){
    // The list items
    var $listItems = $("#navigation li");
    // Classes we want to use
    var classes = "red yellow green blue black".split(" ");
    // Create a copy of the classes
    var classesToUse = classes.slice(0);

    $listItems.each(function(){
        // Reuse the same classes if we've used all up
        if (classesToUse.length === 0) { classesToUse = classes.slice(0); }
        // Generate a random class, remove that from classesToUse
        // and then add it to the element
        $(this).addClass(
            classesToUse.splice(
                Math.floor(Math.random() * classesToUse.length), 
                1
            ).join("")
        );
    });
});​
```

If you want a random color on each hover, do this:

```
$(function(){
    // The list items
    var $listItems = $("#navigation li");
    // Classes we want to use
    var classes = "red yellow green blue black".split(" ");
    // Function to generate a random class
    function getRandomClass() {
        return classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length)]
    }
    // Bind to hover so that we can generate a new class
    $listItems.hover(function(e){
        var $elm = $(this); 
        if (e.type === "mouseenter") {
            // Generate new class, add it to dataset and class
            var randomClass = getRandomClass();
            $elm.data("class", randomClass).addClass(randomClass);
        } else {
            // Remove previous class, if any
            $elm.removeClass($elm.data("class"));
        }
    });
});
```

See [test-case at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/Ma9Ja/)

Comment: Yes but if i add more list items here it stop coloring them?

Comment: No it doesn't. But with this implementation you need one color per list item. Thought it would be better not to have any duplicate colors.

Comment: It doesn't randomise mate, It's a little too extensive, you can do this very simply, have a look at my post @MarcusEkwall

Comment: @Shannon What are you talking about? The splice will pick a random item from `classesToUse` and then use that. When all classes have been used up, it will start randomizing from the the classes all over again.

Comment: Ah. It's not randomizing on hover, that's right. His question was too diffuse to make that out.

Comment: He asked for random colours to be assigned every time the user hovers, if you hover over one of your links over and over it's still the same colour. @MarcusEkwall

Comment: @MarcusEkwall I know, it wasn't the best description of what he was after at all

Comment: @Shannon Updated my example. Not that fond of using `.sort` to shuffle the array.

Comment: Why? The function is specifically built for arrays @MarcusEkwall

Comment: @Shannon Because you are traversing the whole array and shuffling indices around, instead of just accessing a random index. It's slower and will be harder to modify later on since you don't know what's where.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, something like this? : **[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fGcQk/2/)**

A color can't be next to the same color. But, it's a random selection, so there can be twice the same color, even if all the colors have not been picked yet.

**Edited with `hover`**

```
var myColors = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'yellow'], previousRandom = '';

$(function() {
    var li = $('#navigation li');
    li.each(function(i){
        var t = $(this), random;
        do{
            random = Math.floor((Math.random() * myColors.length ));
        }while(random == previousRandom);
        t.addClass(myColors[random]);
        previousRandom = random;
    });

    li.hover(
        function(){ $(this).siblings().addClass('neutral'); },
        function(){ $(this).siblings().removeClass('neutral'); }
    );
});​
```